# difference between revoking a refresh token vs invalidating it in cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I read here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-revocation.html that revoking a refresh token will invalidate an access token.

and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminUserGlobalSignOut.html it says that globalSignout will invalidate a refresh token and won't affect the access/id token.

What is the difference between invalidating a token and revoking one? When to call revoke token if globalSignOut won't do it?

Amplify signout of cognito https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js/#sign-out does result in revoking the token. Does it mean that if I used aws-sdk for globalSignOut, I should be taking care of revoking a refresh token explicitly because it only invalidates it without affecting the Id or access token?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the difference between refresh and access tokens:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html

Access tokens are short lived and are used to access resources. Invalidating an access token means that it can't be longer used to access a resource.

Refresh token last longer (30 days), are created when a user logs in and are used to create access tokens. They aren't used to access resources. Revoking a refresh token means that it can't be used any longer for creating an access token.